# Firebase sign out is not working in flutter application

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am implementing the the firebase sign out in flutter application based on the provider id which is not working at all right now.

I am executing the below code.

```
FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
                if(_auth.currentUser != null) {
                User user =  _auth.currentUser;
               var userset =  user.providerData[0].providerId;

               if(userset == 'google.com'){
                 print('google provider');
                 await GoogleSignIn().signOut(); 
           //Firebase sign out navigation to the login page


                 
             } else {

                 _auth.signOut();
           //Firebase sign out navigation to the login page
                 print('sign out done successfully');
                                }



                }
```

The code is executed, but the auth state maintains the user logged in status, whether sign in or sign out and upon reloading the app it does not go to the login page and it goes to the home page.

How should I check whether the sign out was successful or not?

Auth State handling in app when the app reloads

```
Widget _handleAuth() {
    return StreamBuilder<User>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        return (!snapshot.hasData)
            ? LoginPage()
            : HomePage();
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: not working means ? exactly what you want ? because it looks your code is right

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede the code is right somewhere, but the thing is when the app reloads it goes to the home page of the app when the user is signed out and not to the login page. please guide me some kind of check to ensure successfully sign out. and the auth state change.

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede please check the auth state handling of the page I made the change in the question

Comment: Please check what output is given by user snapshot once print it and then check may be this will help for you

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede, I checked it by printing in the console it is maintaining the user state even after the log out, this is happening after implementing google sign in , earlier email password was working fine

Comment: FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut() is working and not the google sign in out one @ShubhamNarkhede

Comment: Have you stored any session value in shared preference ??

Comment: _auth.currentUser() is actually calling from the local cache.   and precisely how/where are you calling that authStateChanges() stream?

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede but not for google sign in implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also sign out from firebase even if you are using google provider:

```
if(userset == 'google.com'){
   print('google provider');
   await GoogleSignIn().signOut();
   _auth.signOut();
 }
```